# Как сохранять достижения игроков в Linux?

Tags: delphi, linux, разработка-игр, lazarus

Делаю логическую игру для linux. Программирую на lazarus (бесплатный аналог Delphi). Надо как- то сохранять достижения игроков. В винде можно было в реестре хранить, а как в линуксе? Правильный подход какой?

Comment: @iTeam, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Сохраненки лучше на файлах делать, а не реестре, чтобы при копировании игры, например, через флэшку все результаты тоже были перенесены.

Comment: XML для сохраняшек, думаю, пойдет и будет удобен для понимания в процессе отладки.

Comment: Ну например, если я решу сохранять в файл набранный рекорд в игре, то куда мне его сохранять? В какую папку?

Comment: @iTeam, куда угодно, где разрешат права учетки.

Comment: >  то куда мне его сохранять

@iTeam, в линуксе обычно это директория `~/.имя_программы`.

Comment: Не нужно сохранять в `~/.имя_программы` - не нужно загаживать домашний каталог. Для этого есть каталог `~/.config/имя_программы`. Вроде даже есть специальные функции для получения подобного каталога.

Хранить в xml можно, но есть куда более удобные форматы. Например, json.

Answer (score 1):

У Linux нет реестра. Есть нечто похожее на него у GNOME, но xml'и.
Для кросс-платформенности, храните данные в файлах типа XML или JSON.